# Backbone.js: this.model in event is first model rendered, instead of the model associated with DOM element

Tags: backbone.js, jsfiddle

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/umgauper/jnf8B/743/

I'm trying to create a basic shopping cart app. When an item is clicked, I want its title and price added to the shopping cart table.

I am creating a separate instance of the view for each model. However, when an item is clicked, the table data that is added is always the model data for the item1 model, instead of the model data I would expect to be associated with the clicked DOM element. What do I have to change in order to get the model data of the clicked element?

```js
var app = app || {};
var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        order: '',
        title: '',
        price: 0.01,
        inCart: false
            }
});


var item1 = new Item({order: 1, title: "shoes", price: 30.00});
var item2 = new Item({order: 2, title: "socks", price: 5.00});
var item3 = new Item({order: 3, title: "shirt", price: 20.00});

var ItemsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({model: Item});

var items = new ItemsCollection([item1, item2, item3]);

app.ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($("#item-template").html()),
    initialize: function() {
        this.render()
    },
    render: function() {
        $("#display").append(this.template(this.model.attributes));
    },
    el: "#container",
    events: {
        'click .title': 'moveToCart'
    },
    moveToCart: function(e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var title = this.model.get("title");
        var price = this.model.get("price");
        $("table").append("<tr><td>" + title + "</td><td>" + price + "</td></tr>");
    }
});


var itemView1 = new app.ItemView({model: item1});
var itemView2 = new app.ItemView({model: item2});
var itemView3 = new app.ItemView({model: item3});
```

```html
 <div id="container">
  <div id="display">

  </div>
  <table id="cart">
      <thead>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </thead>

  </table>
  </div>
  <script type="text/template" id="item-template">
    <div>
        <p class="title"><%= title %></p>
        <p class="price">$<%= price %></p>
    </div>
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that all your `app.ItemView`s share the same `el`:

```
app.ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //...
    el: "#container",
```

and the events are bound to the `el` through delegation. The result is that your events are all confused because everyone is trying to listen for the same event on the same element.

The easiest solution is to move the `<div>` out of your `#item-template` template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="item-template">
    <p class="title"><%= title %></p>
    <p class="price">$<%= price %></p>
</script>
```

and make it the `el` for the `ItemView`. A Backbone view creates an empty `<div>` as its `el` if you don't specify the `el` any other way so you can just drop the `el` declaration from `ItemView`. You'd also need to adjust `render` to account for the new structure:

```
render: function() {
    this.$el.append(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    $('#display').append(this.el);
    return this;
}
```

The `return this` at the end of `render` is standard practice so that you can say things like:

```
$x.append(view.render().el);
```

Moving the `$('#display').append(...)` call up one level would also be common and would help keep the view self contained. Also notice that I switched to `this.model.toJSON()` instead of `this.model.attributes`; pretending that `attributes` doesn't exist is generally a good idea so that you don't accidentally go behind Backbone's back and confuse things.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/cad0kxee/

Comment: Aha! Now that you've pointed it out, it seems obvious that each view should have its own el. Thanks for your help! And for the reminder to add the 'return this' statement in render.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jnf8B/765/) is another implementation of your task.

I guess it's already clear for you that it is a bad practice to initialize a lot of `Backbone.View`s with the same `el` selector.

In my implementation I have separated the item view and the container view so you will have:

```
app.ContentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($("#item-template").html()),
    render: function () {
        this.$el.append(this.template(this.model.attributes));
        return this;
    }, 
    events: {
        'click .title': 'moveToCart'
    },
    moveToCart: function(e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var title = this.model.get("title");
        var price = this.model.get("price");
        $("table").prepend("<tr><td>" + title + "</td><td>" + price + "</td></tr>");
    }

});
```

And "collectionView"

```
app.ContentsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.render()
    },
    render: function() {
        var that = this;
        this.buffer = document.createDocumentFragment();
        this.collection.each(function(model){
            var itemView = new app.ContentView({model: model});
            that.buffer.appendChild(itemView.render().el);
        });
        this.$el.append(this.buffer);
    },
    el: "#display"
});
```

I guess you will add collection of items/products dynamically, not one by one and this approach will be helpful. Note that I have used [documentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) here for caching.

**Another note:** If you decided to implement an app/single page application with Backbone you need to try [Backbone.Marionette](http://marionettejs.com/) as well. It will automate a lot of staff for you and will save a lot of time.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I see, your solution will be much better if I need to add a lot of items. Thank you! And thanks for the tip about Marionette-I'll look into it.

Comment: `this.collection.each(function(model) { ... }, this)` would be better than messing around with `that` and `_.each(collection, ...)`, no? And you might want to check what your `_.each` callback is actually getting passed, `_.each(collection, ...)` and `collection.each(...)` aren't quite the same thing.

Comment: @muistooshort - Sure, _.each(collection, ...) and collection.each(...) are different. In the end of the JS code in fiddle, you will find that I'm passing collection as array of Backbone models, so why I have used   1st version. In case of Backbone.Collection we need to use 2nd one.

Comment: Passing the collection as an array when you have a collection is a bit strange. And storing an array in the `collection` property is going to confuse anyone with any Backbone experience.